# unclear use of an array more elements then pre defined

Tags: java, arrays

i have to following code taken from the complete reference

it about the following syntax:-   " hist[y]++; " which appears  there
its about creating histogram of brightness values of img.

i wonder what it means  in the code  since  hist[]  is defined as int[256] , while the itteration here  is much larger then 256.

```
int hist[] = new int[256];   <<<<<<<<defined here 256 elements
```

...

```
for (int i=0; i<iw*ih; i++) {
    int p = pixels[i];
    int r = 0xff & (p >> 16);
    int g = 0xff & (p >> 8);
    int b = 0xff & (p);
    int y = (int) (.33 * r + .56 * g + .11 * b);
    hist[y]++;     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<here many more elements
}
```

etc.  etc..

Comment: Fix your code formatting and indentation.

Comment: What do you mean, "here many more elements"?  What is `y` when `hist[y]` is incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `hist[y]++;`     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here many more elements

You're perhaps mixing up the expression `hist[y]++` with `hist[y++]` or confusing `y` with the loop index `i`.

The expression `hist[y]++` simply increments the value at index `y` by one. And the index `y` is set in the line above to

```
int y = (int) (.33 * r + .56 * g + .11 * b);
```

Since `r`, `g` and `b` are all `<= 255` the maximum value of `y` is

```
  .33*255 + .56*255 + .11*255
= (.33 + .56 + .11) * 255
= 1 * 255
```

so an array of 256 elements will suffice.

Comment: i am sorry! i still dont see the what hist[y] ++  is doing here.
there is no loop for hist , and its actual value is not assigned ,or  added to any other parameter .

where am i wrong here ?